# Why can't I access matrices in hlsl pixel-shader?

Tags: wpf, for-loop, hlsl, pixel-shader

I'm learning how to create effects for wpf using hlsl.
I'm currently trying to make a simple effect that marks edges in an image.
I want too use the Sobel operator for this, so I set a public float2x3 in my hlsl code, but I can't seem to access elements in that matrix.

I've tried manually inputting the proper values and it works, but not when I use a loop.

```
sampler2D imageSampler : register(s0);
float imageWidth : register(c0);
float imageHeight : register(c1);
float threshold : register(c2);

float2x3 op =
{
    1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -2.0f, -1.0f
};


float grayScale(float3 color)
{
    return (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3;
}

float4 GetEdgeLoop(float2 coord, float2 pixelSize)
{
    float2 current;
    float avrg = 0;

    float holder;
    float gsHolder;

    current.x = coord.x - pixelSize.x;
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        current.y = coord.y - pixelSize.y;
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            holder = op[x][y];
            gsHolder = grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, current).rgb);
            avrg += gsHolder * holder;

            current.y += pixelSize.y;
        }
        current.x += pixelSize.x * 2;
    }

    avrg = abs(avrg / 8);

    if (avrg > threshold)
        return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);

    return tex2D(imageSampler, coord);
}

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float2 pixelSize = (1 / imageWidth, 1 / imageHeight);

    return GetEdgeLoop(uv, pixelSize);
}
```

This method should return the color red for strong enough edges.
This does return red sometimes, but clearly not for edges.

I have another method for detecting edges that actually works, but it samples the required pixels manually:

```
float4 GetEdge(float2 coord, float2 pixelSize)
{
    float avrg = 0;

    avrg += grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, float2(coord.x - pixelSize.x, coord.y - pixelSize.y)).rgb) * 1;
    avrg += grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, float2(coord.x - pixelSize.x, coord.y)).rgb) * 2;
    avrg += grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, float2(coord.x - pixelSize.x, coord.y + pixelSize.y)).rgb) * 1;

    avrg += grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, float2(coord.x + pixelSize.x, coord.y - pixelSize.y)).rgb) * (-1);
    avrg += grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, float2(coord.x + pixelSize.x, coord.y)).rgb) * (-2);
    avrg += grayScale(tex2D(imageSampler, float2(coord.x + pixelSize.x, coord.y + pixelSize.y)).rgb) * (-1);

    avrg = abs(avrg / 8);

    if (avrg > threshold)
        return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);

    return tex2D(imageSampler, coord);
}
```

This method isn't very elegant and I want to replace it.

Comment: Can you post the full source to your shader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on shaders in WPF, but in the code that you provided you don't specify any registers for your input, so it's not accessible from the pixel shader code. I would expect something like this to be part of your code:

```
sampler2D implicitInputSampler : register(S0);
float opacity : register(C0);
```

(The first definition is a texture sampler, the second one a floating number register.)

You need to 'declare' the objects that will be passed into the shader function. Microsoft's guide to shader effect writing has a nice example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect?view=netframework-4.8. Here's the code for posterity:

```
// Threshold shader 
// Object Declarations

sampler2D implicitInput : register(s0);
float threshold : register(c0);
float4 blankColor : register(c1);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pixel Shader
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(implicitInput, uv);
    float intensity = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3;

    float4 result;
    if (intensity > threshold)
    {
        result = color;
    }
    else
    {
        result = blankColor;
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can see that the code declares a texture sampler, a float and a float4 (vector with 4 floats) as input. You can then bind to these through DependencyProperties like this:

```
    #region Input dependency property

    public Brush Input
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(InputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty =
        ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("Input", typeof(ThresholdEffect), 0);

    #endregion

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Threshold dependency property

    public double Threshold
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ThresholdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThresholdProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThresholdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Threshold", typeof(double), typeof(ThresholdEffect),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(0.5, PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));

    #endregion

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region BlankColor dependency property

    public Color BlankColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BlankColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BlankColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlankColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BlankColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ThresholdEffect),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent, PixelShaderConstantCallback(1)));

    #endregion
```

Do note that the PixelShaderConstantCallback has an int parameter which let's you specify the index of the register to which you want to bind the value.

Edit: Ok, so I've read up some more on this topic, played around with your code and got it to work. Here are the changes I've done in no particular order:

- I've read that you should declare your array as static const. It does not change during the execution of the shader and it apparently 'might' allow some minor compiler optimizations.
- I've changed the float2x3 to float3x3 to fit a Laplace kernel - as we want the edges working from all sides of the image.
- I've changed the grayscale function to use weights for the luminosity approach.

Here's the relevant code:

```
static const float3x3 laplace =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 8.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
};

float grayScaleByLumino(float3 color)
{
    return (0.299 * color.r + 0.587 * color.g + 0.114 * color.b);
}

float4 GetEdgeGeorge(float2 coord, float2 pixelSize)
{
    float2 current = coord;
    float avrg = 0;

    float kernelValue;
    float4 currentColor;
    float grayScale;

    float4 result;

    current.x = coord.x - pixelSize.x;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        current.y = coord.y - pixelSize.y;
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            kernelValue = laplace[x][y];
            grayScale = grayScaleByLumino(tex2D(imageSampler, current).rgb);
            avrg += grayScale * kernelValue;

            current.y += pixelSize.y;
        }
        current.x += pixelSize.x;
    }

    avrg = abs(avrg / 8);

    if (avrg > threshold)
    {
        result = float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        result = tex2D(imageSampler, coord);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The whole solution I've created is available here: https://github.com/georgethejournalist/WPFShaders. I hope this helps.

Comment: I left out some information when writing the question so I understand if it wasn't very clear.

Thanks for trying to help, I've fixed the question.